# Find 2 numbers that are as close as possible to each other and when multiplied give integer X

Tags: math, geometry

The input is number of cells to layout, say X = 6.
I need to layout them in square (or rectangle that is as close to a square as possible).
For X = 6 the rectangle would be 3 columns in width and 2 rows in height.

For X-es that have integer roots, like 4 and 9, this is easy. The number of columns and rows is simply a square of X. What would be the math to get the rows and columns for other scenarios?

Comment: Find the (real) square root of `X`, then nudge it up / down a bit until you find satisfactory integers.  And figure out what you want to do with primes and numbers like `74`.

Comment: A different approach: find all the prime factors of X with multiplicity, then distribute them into two bins so that the product of the first bin is as close as possible to the product of the second bin.

Comment: A different approach: decide the limits of the attractiveness, for your purposes, of rectangularity (eg you might like 2x3 (and all multiples) but dislike 2x43) and fit every X into the next nice grid it fits into and live with a few blank cells (eg you might prefer to fit 86 into 9x10 rather than 2x43).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def squarish(x):
    """returns rows and cols of a rectangle of x cells that best approximates a square"""
    # TODO add an isprime check and handle it as you want
    sqrt = np.sqrt(x)
    if int(sqrt) == sqrt:
        return int(sqrt), int(sqrt)

    rows = int(sqrt)
    while rows > 1:
        cols = x / rows
        if int(cols) == cols:
            return rows, int(cols)
        else:
            rows -= 1
```